# EPPlus DeleteRow does not shift rows up

Tags: c#, delete-row, epplus

I have an if-statement which if met hides the row in my sheet. I need the row to be entirely deleted and then shifted up.

Using DeleteRow which is supposedly supposed to auto shift up but it does not. The end result is my Excel sheet still contains those entries just that the entire row is now blank.

I'm using EPPlus v4.5.2.1

```cs
if (!computerMap.ContainsKey(systems[i])) { 
    //ws.Row(2 + i).Hidden = true; //commented out
    ws.DeleteRow(2 + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 overloaded methods, and you should use the one with 3 parameters.

```cs
DeleteRow(int rowFrom, int rows, bool shiftOtherRowsUp);
```

This will delete a continues region of data. If you need to delete multiple non-continues regions then figure out all regions you need to delete and delete them in  a loop using this method.